# Jquery/Javascript regex: filter, allow multiple tags to be typed in to select that category, jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, filter, split

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/AtkNW/

The goal is to take the value of an textbox, which will have multiple keywords in it seperated by a space, then filter the list to show the item(s) that contain all of those keywords. Right now, I can only type those keywords in as they are listed in `<span class="tags">`.

I would like to be able to type them in, but out of order, and have it still only keep the item with all those keywords as the visible item. I think I might have to use `.split(" ")` somewhere in here... hmm...

```
<li>entertainment
    <span class="tags">tv radio dance opera</span>      
</li>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#filter").keyup(function () {
    var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    if (length > 1) {
        $(".filtered li").each(function () {
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).addClass("hidden");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("hidden");
                count++;
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.filtered li').removeClass("hidden")
            count++;
    }
    $("#filter-count").text(count);
});
```

would anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly as you suspected, you'll need to use String.split() to split the user input, and match the words one-by-one against your tags.

Modified code as:

```
$("#filter").keyup(function() {
    var filter = $(this).val(),
        count = 0;
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    if (length > 1) {
        var filter_tags = filter.split(" "); // Split user input by spaces
        $(".filtered li").each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var matches = true;
            // Match each splitted string against the whole tags string
            $.each(filter_tags, function(i, a_filter) {  
                if ($this.text().indexOf(a_filter) === -1) {
                    matches = false;
                }
            });
            if (matches) {
                $this.removeClass("hidden");
                count++;
            } else {
                $this.addClass("hidden");
            }
        });        
    } else {
        $('.filtered li').removeClass("hidden")
        count++;
    }

    $("#filter-count").text(count);
});
```

You might need to pass a smart regexp to the split to allow both for spaces and commas as separators.

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/AtkNW/31/

Comment: dude you're awesome, that's perfect. i don't know how I would even start to go about allowing for commas with regexp, just allowing for spaces is probably good enough, i think... i spent hours trying to figure this out last night and spending more time trying to figure out the commas isn't worth the frustration. Annnnd now my 6 month old should be waking up soon.. **[head explodes]**

  


    but seriously you saved my monitor from having a tea party with my fist.

Comment: Use filter.split(/[\s,]+/) for allowing both commas and spaces as separators, it will lead to a better user experience. Example updated at http://jsfiddle.net/AtkNW/33/

Comment: thank you so much man. When you fixed my broken script, it lost the ability to be case insensitive, is there a way to bring that back?

Comment: Sure, just use "$this.text().toLowerCase().indexOf(a_filter)" instead of "$this.text().indexOf(a_filter)" when comparing the tags (and make sure you only use lowercase tags, when defining them).